# Getting the generated key after SQL Insert with Spring JDBC

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to retrieve the generated Key after inserting a new row into my database table. I tried to achieve this with an `KeyHolder` and a `PreparedStatement` but get this exception:

> org.springframework.dao.DataRetrievalFailureException:
>        The generated key is not of a supported numeric type.
>         Unable to cast [oracle.sql.ROWID] to [java.lang.Number]

So it seems like the update method of the JDBCTemplate returns the row id, which is not what I wanted to achieve. Here is the code I wrote for doing this:

```
String sql = Sql.CREATE_VORGANG;
final KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {           

  @Override
  public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection)
                throws SQLException {
     PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
     ps.setString(1, fuehrungskraftPersonalnummer);
     ps.setString(2, mitarbeiterPersonalnummer);
     ps.setString(3, statusId);
     return ps;
   }
}, holder);
```

The table uses a trigger that generates a new value with a sequence each time a new row is inserted. That value is inserted into the colum ID_VORGANG of the table.

Am I missing something obvious here?

EDIT:
The executed SQL-Statement:

```
Insert into TRAL_VORGANG (FK_PERSONALNUMMER, MA_PERSONALNUMMER, STATUS_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Add your sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
long id = holder.getKey().longValue();
```